# Indentation problem with python3 and vim

Tags: python, vim

A sample of my python file is

```
def __init__(self, csvFile, chunksize=10000):
        self.newName = csvFile[:-4]
        import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()
        self.csvFile=csvFile
        self.chunksize=int(chunksize)
        self.headers_without_timestamp = header_without_timestamp 

        self.total_rows = 0
        self.username=username
        self.password=password
        self.dbname="data"
```

and it is well written.

I have the little error, but I can't fix it. When I ran the command `python3 Final_Fast_Version_Waqar.py ~/home/Data/DCIX_OB.csv 1000 7`, I got

```
  File "Final_Fast_Version_Waqar.py", line 37
    import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()
                                ^
TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation
```

It is a problem related to the vim editor I guess because I set up an Ubuntu server and installed vim very recently. How can I fix the indentation error?

Comment: Were you using Vim to write the script?

Comment: Yes, write this script with Vim.

Comment: The error says it all actually, you're mixing tabs and spaces. Double check that you only use one of the two (4 spaces is preferred) for indentation.

Answer (score 2):

You have most likely mixed tabs and spaces in your python file, you must use only one of them.

In order to find the problem you can use the command `:set list` to have vim list all non-printable characters and see where the problem is. Tabs will be shown as `^I` spaces will be shown as normal.